# RegEx for number, not more than 3 digits and can have decimal that is either .50 or .00

Tags: javascript, objective-c, regex, swift

I need to validate money value in which the user may only input up to 3 digits and may have decimal which is only by .50.

Thats is: 123.50, 2, 123, 123.00

Thanks! Been trying this for some time. Always feeling.

I am developing an iOS app.

Comment: How does your regex look now and what have you tried?

Comment: @dzk im using ^[0-9]{3}$". just getting exact 3 digits.

Comment: ^[0-9]{3}(\.(00|50)?)$ try and see if this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should accomplish what you wanted:

```
^[0-9]{0,3}(\.(00|50)?)$
```

It matches your results.

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/cZ6wV2/1).

Comment: Just change the `{3}` to `{0,3}`, as he was asking for up to three digits. In any case, solid answer!

Comment: You're right! I just edited, thanks =D Maybe I should put {1,3} ? But I am sure he gets it now so he can edit it however he wants to make it suitable.

Comment: @G4bri3l Thanks! Works perfect!

Comment: @FranzHenrideGuzman glad I could help ;), mark it as the correct answer if it worked =D

Answer (score 0):

decimal part is **only** either `00` or `50`, then try this:

```
/^((\d{0,3})(\.50|\.00)?)$/
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tP8sB9/11)

---

decimal part is between `00` and `50`, then try this:

```
/^(\d{0,3}(\.50|\.[0-4]{1}[0-9]{1})?)$/
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tP8sB9/10)

---

Note, you can grab

- the number: `$1`
- integer part: `$2`
- decimal part: `$3`

Comment: Now you're allowing any decimals between `.0` and `.55` including single-value ones and also e.g. `.23`.